# How to add multiple users in Yocto based on machine

Tags: yocto

I have 5 machines in my Yocto workspace. Is there a way to add users based on machine type?

For example:

- Machine 1 has `user1`, `user2`
- Machine 2 has `user1`, `user2`, `user3`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

The [`useradd-example.bb`](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta-skeleton/recipes-skeleton/useradd/useradd-example.bb?h=hardknott) recipe demonstrates how to write a recipe that creates multiple users, each in their own package.

First, you could follow that example's pattern to create packages for each of the users you need:

```py
# customusers.bb
inherit useradd

PACKAGES =+ "${PN}-user1 ${PN}-user2 ${PN}-user3"
USERADD_PACKAGES = "${PN}-user1 ${PN}-user2 ${PN}-user3"

USERADD_PARAM_${PN}-user1 = "-u 1001 -d /home/user1 -r user1"
USERADD_PARAM_${PN}-user2 = "-u 1002 -d /home/user2 -r user1"
USERADD_PARAM_${PN}-user3 = "-u 1003 -d /home/user3 -r user1"
```

Then, in each `machine.conf` file you can add the appropriate packages using [`MACHINE_ESSENTIAL_EXTRA_RDEPENDS`](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html#term-MACHINE_ESSENTIAL_EXTRA_RDEPENDS), e.g.:

```py
# machine1.conf
MACHINE_ESSENTIAL_EXTRA_RDEPENDS += "\
    customusers-user1 \
    customusers-user2 \
"
```

```py
# machine2.conf
MACHINE_ESSENTIAL_EXTRA_RDEPENDS += "\
    customusers-user1 \
    customusers-user2 \
    customusers-user3 \
"
```